# How to transfer data from a certain time period into existing iPhone without overwriting it?

Tags: iphone, backup, migration, time

I need to prepare my old iPhone 12 for trade-in, but there were a couple of months recently where I had to actually use the 12 while my 14 pro was, let's say "on vacation" (long story).  Unfortunately, when I switched back to the 12 I did not do a data transfer from the 14 back to the 12, I just activated the eSIM and kept rolling.

I'm not using the 12 anymore, but now I have a 2-month gap in history for the period while I was using the 12 again, and since that was pretty recent, I'm missing some still-relevant SMS conversations and not sure what else.

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to fill the gap by restoring the data for this chunk of time from the 12 (or iCloud?) to my current iPhone since I expect it will otherwise be lost when I factory reset the 12 for trade-in.  The 12 has been backing up to iCloud but I assume if I restore one of those backups on the current phone it will overwrite the existing data, so I'll still end up with a gap, just in a different time period.  Please correct me if I'm wrong there, and thanks for any suggestions!